# uploading to server in laravel and then showing image in SPA

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, intervention

I am doing the following in a controller to upload an image,

```
$img = Image::make($request->file->getRealPath());
    $img->backup();
    $img->fit(666, 461)->encode('jpg', 65);
    //$img->stream();
    //dd($request->user()->slug.'/desktop/' . time() . '.jpg');
    $urlLarge = \Storage::put('/public/storage/'.$request->user()->slug.'/desktop/' . time() . '.jpg', $img->__toString());
    $img->fit(296, 205)->encode('jpg', 65);
    $img->stream();
    $urlMob = \Storage::put('/public/storage/'.$request->user()->slug.'/mobile/' . time() . '.jpg', $img->__toString());
```

This returns the following URL,

> http://localhost:8000/performer/desktop/1593464373.jpg

However when I access this URL I get routed to my SPA 404 page, as I assume the catch all web route in web.php,

Route::any('/{any}', 'HomeController@index')->where('any', '.*');

What am I doing wrong? I have also trued to run,

`php artisan storage:link` but no change.

Comment: You have confirmed the file is actually created in the public folder you have shown? Also, your nginx rules likely will not send image extensions to php but try to serve them itself, if you are using nginx.

Comment: Images are getting created and I am using Apache.

Comment: I am not an apache expert, but if you have verified the image is in the location you have specified, and apache is configured to serve files statically from that folder, then I am not sure what the issue is. If it is configured to serve statically, you wont be able to debug inside laravel, because your index.php will not be called.